# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in signals

Tags: django, model

I  tried to insert data into the table Account, but I keep getting this error message.
I delete all my migrations and make migrations again but I keep getting this error.

Here is my models.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone               = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    gender              = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    section             = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    dept                = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    batch               = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    USN                 = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    DOB                 = models.DateField(default='1998-01-01')
    profile_image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='student/profile_images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    address             = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    nationality         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    guardian_name       = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    guardian_number     = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    guardian_address    = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    blood_group         = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)

    exam_name           = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    background          = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    passing_year        = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    score               = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    school_name         = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    country             = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    certificate         = models.FileField(upload_to='certificates/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is Account model.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    unid                    = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group                   = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user_permissions        = models.ManyToManyField(
                                                Permission,
                                                verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True,
                                                help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
                                                related_name="user_set",
                                                related_query_name="user",
                                            )
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    registered              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

so what I did is that when I create account if the is_student is True I create a signals that going to create student model for that account instance automatically.

here is the signals

```
def create_student_or_teacher(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_student:
            Student.objects.create(
                user=instance,
                USN=instance.unid,
            )
        elif instance.is_teacher:
            Teacher.objects.create(
                user=instance,
                id=instance.unid,
            )
```

So when I create the account for student the tracker will highlight in the signals `Student.objects.create(...)` 
If you have any idea I hope it would help me.

UPDATED:

When I'm creating teacher it is working find. 
here is the teacher model

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone               = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    gender              = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    salary              = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    school              = models.ForeignKey(School, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section             = models.ForeignKey(Section, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user                = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id                  = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    dept                = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    DOB                 = models.DateField(default='1980-01-01')
    profile_image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='teacher/profile_images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    nationality         = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    address             = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Try removing the Foreign keys one by one and narrow it down to the one causing the issue.

Comment: why in Student model  `models.CharField(primary_key='True',` true is a string instead of boolean? (see docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key  )

may be problem in this arg?

Comment: no as long as it it unique it is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after few hours I solved my error it was simple

in the section I set default value which was not exist

so I just change the value to an exist one and that was it.